# WinForms ProgressBar memory leak

Tags: winforms, memory-leaks, progress-bar

It seems like *Garbage Collector* doesn't clean up resources connected with `ProgressBar` control, and it causes the continuous growth of the number of *User Objects* of my *WinForms* application (seen in Task Manager).

Here is a sample code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    GC.Collect();
    panel1.Controls.Clear();
    Random rnd = new Random((int)DateTime.Now.Ticks);
    ProgressBar pB = new ProgressBar() { Value = rnd.Next(0, 100) };
    panel1.Controls.Add(pB);
}
```

When the `Button` is clicked, the number of *User Objects* increases by 2-3. When the number of *User Objects* becomes 10000 an `Exception` is thrown. How can I prevent the growth of *User Objects*?

> Please excuse any spelling or grammatical mistakes, English isn't my
>   first language

Comment: Exception was System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): Error creating window handle. It appeared because of User Objects growth. The problem is solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to call `.Dispose()` on your old progress bar before you clear the panel.

```
foreach (Control c in panel1.Controls)
    c.Dispose();
```